# Is it possible to display WAAS enabled GPS Flightlines on older mechanical flight directors such as S-tec?

Tags: avionics

We are in the research process of a panel upgrade in a M5 Maule. 
The ac is used for transportation and aerial survey to support ground survey. We frequently fly tight, low alt grids. Lateral and vertical deviation limits are 50’. 
Is it possible to display WAAS enabled GPS Flightlines on older mechanical flight directors such as S-tec?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  No.

Comment: I think you may elaborate a bit more the context. Moreover, try to use less abbreviations or explicit them (e.g. ac, alt grid).

Comment: Thanks, my first draft was quite lengthy and It seems that I over edited.

Comment: We have an occasional need to fly multiple parallel flight lines with a high degree of precision. We can purchase computer software designed for this purpose but its quite bulky, hard to mount anywhere near the flight instruments, and very expensive.

Comment: Avionics shops are quite busy these days and are not interested in low budget jobs. So we are looking at options. An EFIS system would be great but far too expensive.